# Air Flow through non-uniform size Duct with Holes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, air

[image]We are a manufacturing plant and this is one query which we could not find the answer too. So, came here asking for help.

**Problem:** In the attached image, you can see the air/steam inlet from the top which then goes through the non-uniform duct which has holes all over where the yellow arrows go. So, the question was that:

**a.) Will equal air/steam will go through opposite end holes?
b.) If not, which side(Narrow/Wide) will be giving out more air/steam compared to the other one?**

I did some research online and according to that the narrow side will provide less air/steam compared to the wide side holes. Need your help guys as this query both interests me and is part of my job too...

Comment: Why not measure the narrow side outlet velocity profile  (pitot tube) and calculate the mass flow... the difference to the inlet mass flow will tell you.

Comment: You might post this to the engineering stack exchange instead. Also, add a reference to the online research that convinced you of your current conclusion. Finally, what background do you have and what principles are you applying to analyze the problem?

Comment: I have a numerical model for the sprinkler  with 10 holes. Maybe it will be useful. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477796/fundamentals-of-estimating-sprinkler-pressure/477953#477953